# Is it possible to implement an [exclusiveto] interface from a Windows type on my own runtimeclass?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm currently experimenting with [Holographic Remoting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Holographic.Remoting.Simulation) and have discovered that various parts of the Holographic API usually implemented by Windows come from elsewhere.
For example my `HolographicSpace` comes from `Microsoft.Perception.Simulation.dll` which is the library linked above.

I'm curious to find out how this was done, so I created a new C++/WinRT component and tried to derive from `Windows.Graphics.Holographic.IHolographicSpace` in my `.idl` file, but the MIDL compiler would give me this error message:
`error MIDL5051: [msg]use of the [exclusiveto] interface is not valid, use the runtimeclass for which this interface is exclusiveto instead`.

Fair enough, otherwise what would be the use of `[exclusiveto]`?

However, the question still remains: How can an external component pretend it implements a type from the Windows namespace? I mean I could theoretically use the `implements<>` struct template and implement all the required COM interfaces on my type, but that wouldn't play well with the whole MIDL toolchain since my code is partially generated from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/WinRT does not restrict what interfaces you can implement. You can thus implement exclusive interfaces. This can be handy for implementing a WinRT class or simply for testing or mocking something. Naturally, this won't be visible to other languages or tools like MIDL since it is just an implementation detail within C++.